# How do you allow a particular http method on elasticsearch6 for indexes with no types?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am taking some courses on udemy on elastic search and trying to set up an elastic search project. I have gotten the bulk api to work and can successfully send batch data into an index on elastic search. But I am having trouble sending data without the bulk api. Because I have read on the elastic search docs that there is a 'false' analogy that a type is like a table in a database and an index is like a database. I decided for this project to create an index for each of the entities that I want to persist which is users and statistics. Therefore I have indices which are called statisitics and users. When I make the following request from postman

```
headers: Content-Type application/json
POST http://localhost:9200/users
```

with body:

```
{"id": 1, "name":"myname"}
```

I get an error

> {"error":"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/users] and method [POST],
>   allowed: [PUT, DELETE, GET, HEAD]","status":405}

How can I allow this http method?

Comment: Because there is conflicting information within the elastic search docs and on tutorials, any other comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I had the same issue using PHP and JAVA, this happen simply because you must add the _type after the index name (described here) :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html

Try `curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/users/_admin` or something similar ;) 
See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html

Comment: Because the docs say there are not as many use cases  where you actually need types as it may seem https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type , and they make the suggestion of splitting up data across multiple indices, I dont have types.... Maybe I should just add types anyway because it seems like everybody uses types.

Comment: Yes but they also suggest to allow a typed search which make easier for you to subdivide your data. But of course I've just seen that it has been removed since Elastic 6.0 https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch#mapping-type 

What's your elastic version in this case ?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch#mapping-type I still see type at least in the body here. So I think the type is your problem, like it was mine ;) Don't hesitate to upvote if it helps you fix ;)

Comment: I just installed it... 6.2

Comment: Ok in this case it should come from the body syntax, this article is full of information on ES6 and it will certainly help you build a POST request, here what I found  https://medium.com/@federicopanini/elasticsearch-6-0-removal-of-mapping-types-526a67ff772  ,  https://dzone.com/articles/the-removal-of-mapping-types-in-elasticsearch-6-th  ,  https://dzone.com/articles/the-removal-of-mapping-types-in-elasticsearch-6-th

Comment: Thanks those are good articles. I didnt realize how recent this 'HUGE' change occurred in elasticsearch. It seems like there is no choice but to not use types if using elasticsearch6 or above.

Comment: I've read those 3 articles and was surprised too as many companies will have to reindex their data. It's not professionnal at all from Elastic

Comment: I found this article useful. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html This works for post/put adding _doc as part of the url was in the tutorials i saw :/

Answer (score 1):

Since version 6.2, we need to use `_doc` for the type.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-use-doc-as-type-despite-it-being-declared-the-preferred-method/113837

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types

In fact, when you say there is "no types" allowed in ElasticSearch, it is false (at least for versions up to 8.x). What is true is that there is only 1 type allowed for each index.